# Artificially cap bandwidth on XP Pro.... possible?

Tags: windows-xp, bandwidth, slow-connection, mstsc

I'm looking for a way to artificially cap the bandwidth of my net connection on XP home to say, 1MB, temporarily. I've had a look at the QoS Packet Scheduler with little luck. Any ideas?

[Boring story]
I want to do this since I wish to test a theory I have for improving the internet experience of people with slow broadband...ie Rural areas, 3G networks etc.

A while ago, I rented a virtual private server for my web-hosting. It was a Windows server, so I could RDP into it. Whilst RDP'd in, browsing was lightning fast - as in, a much better experience than browsing on my local machine (which had a 5mb connection) - I guess because the server was on a FAT pipe, and the TS-compressed screen data was smaller than all the files used to generate the page locally.

I've heard that RDP is pretty usable even with a ~1mb connection - I just want to see whether that is true.
[/Boring story]

Edit: If latency is a bigger issue than bandwidth - which makes perfect sense now I think about is - is there anyway I can mimic high latency on my connection? Thanks

Comment: latency is the real killer with RDP

Comment: RDP is fine for browing static pages, but when you bring in video and flash you start seeing issues.

Comment: I believe the correct term is "Phat" pipe ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html) should do what you want.

RDP will work fine over slow connections (1Mb is plenty) including dial-up speeds.

Comment: not with 16 million colors enabled!